# Media query for higher resolutions dont look good

Tags: html, css

Hi am new to programming and am having this problem so  created a website in a 1366x768 resolution and when  see my webpage in a 1920x1080 resolution its not looking good at all  was wondering if there was a way to fix that  tried with viewport but wont work I know about media query but idont know the specific code

Comment: You'll need to show us an example of relevant code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: IDK how to say this i cant write the whole code of the webpage but the thing is how can i make the webpage look like the one it shows to me but in higher res monitors cuz i tried it and it looks like the divs arent wide enough even if i have them max-width:auto; i got the <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> on but its still doesnt look good

Comment: You need to have designed and coded the webpage with responsiveness in mind. That means for most things using relative units like % and/or those related to the viewport rather than anything fixed like px widths. You also need to have images that are high enough res to show well on whatever viewports your users are likely to be on. When you say 'it is not looking good' what does that mean? Things out of alignment or images looking blurry or.... Perhaps you could start by creating a small snippet in your question which shows whatever problem it is with max-width: auto.

Comment: Oh got it but 1 more question is there any extension for vs code or any website where i can check how my webpage looks like in bigger res monitors

Comment: Are you using your browsers dev tools which will emulate different viewports settings. e.g. on Chrome you can set responsive width and height to whatever you like.

Comment: As I said I am new I Do not know anything about dev tools or anything I am currently redoing my webpage but the width elements that effect the page doing in percentage and I am using zooming out or in to see it it covers the page so if u know anything about making my project a little easier thank you idk anything about dev tools so I am would love some tips from an experienced programmer to a 17yr old old starting to learn Thank you again for replying and tell me if using zoom out or in to check my pages responsiveness is a good idea and if you know some things to make it easier please tell me

Comment: I don’t think zooming is going to help responsiveness checking. Find out how to use your browsers developer tools, in particular the inspect facility which lets you see what code is actually in use for an element. E.g. on Windows Chrome or Edge right click on something on your page and select inspect.